# Joining many-to-many models to allow iteration in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using these models:

```
public class FList
{
    public int FListID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FListItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FListItem> FLists { get; set; }
}

public class FListItem
{
    public int FListID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public virtual FList FList { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FList> FLists { get; set; }
}
```

with this fluent API which creates a composite primary key on FListItem.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FaveListItem>().HasKey(fi => new { fi.FaveListID, fi.ItemID });

modelBuilder.Entity<FList>()
            .HasMany(f => f.Items)
            .WithRequired(fi => fi.FList)
            .HasForeignKey(fi => fi.FListID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(f => f.FLists)
            .WithRequired(fi => fi.Item)
            .HasForeignKey(fi => fi.ItemID);
```

If I add a controller for `FList`, the following scaffolding is created

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var fLists = db.FLists.Include(f => f.User);
    return View(fLists.ToList());
}
```

which allows `fLists` to be iterated on the index view.

What I need to do is include `Items` which can be iterated through for each `fList`. I can't use `Include` because there's no `Items` navigation property on `FList`.

I think I need to `Join` `Items` on `fList` and create a viewModel with an IEnumerable to allow iteration of `Items`.

Please can anybody advise if the above reasoning is correct and if so, assist with the `Join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also `Include` the items:

```
db.FLists.Include(f => f.User)
         .Include(f => f.Items.Select(i => i.Item))
```

I don't know what the view model looks like, but the items of one `FList` can be iterated by

```
fList.Items.Select(i => i.Item)
```

By the way, I'd prefer to name both `ICollection<FListItem>` collections "FListItem", so as not to confuse them with real `Items` or `FLists`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. If you create a viewmodel, you'll specify the navigation property to items in your Flist viewmodel class. Once that's complete, you won't have to right an include, it will just be available automatically.

You viewmodel would look something like...

```
public class FList
{
[Key]
    public int FListID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

}

public class Item
{
[Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FListItem> FLists { get; set; }
}
```